# Excel - Turning time into numbers using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a time diary spreadsheet that was given to me to record times taken for staff to complete different activities. Column A is the start time, column B is the finish time, where column C is the difference, using the formula B3-A3.

In row 3, this gives me answer of 0:01. Is there a way to convert this to "1" using a formula?

i.e. 0:0X becomes X

or, 0:YX becomes YX?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MINUTE()` will convert the time to time in minutes.

Comment: Thanks mate. Tried that initially, but it didn't work. Turns out the formatting was out of whack